# Could not import extension sphinx_panels

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

While trying to use [sphinx_panels](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-panels/) in the rst (reStructuredText), I'm facing an error [Could not import extension sphinx_panels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TfXj.png).

I've added the [extension in the conf.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1bhR.png) as mentioned in the [docs](https://sphinx-panels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation) still facing the issue

I even tried reinstalling but no help, can anyone tell me how to resolve the issue

Comment: I don't know, but the top of the README says "This repository is not actively maintained. Use sphinx-design instead! See the migration guide and this github issue for more information."

Answer (score 0):

Your sphinx version (2.0.1) is too old, SphinxPostTransform is introduced in 2.1.0.

Changelog: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/changes.html#release-2-1-0-released-jun-02-2019

> Add a helper class sphinx.transforms.post_transforms.SphinxPostTransform